# boost asio multithreaded tcp server with synchronous I/O on a given thread

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is to implement a generic multithreaded TCP server that can handle arbitrary requests for usage by 2 different servers with slightly different needs.

My requirements are:

1. A request cannot begin to be processed until an entire initial request has been received. (Essentially, I have a request header of a fixed size that among other things, includes the size of the entire request).
2. Handling a request may result in multiple response messages to the requesting client. I.E., normally, requests can be handled in a single response, but at times, in response to long running database transactions, I need to ping back to the client, letting them know that I'm still working and to not time out the connection.

To achieve this, I've been following fairly closely the HTTP server example #2 from boost v1.44. In general, the example has worked for simple cases. What I've noticed is that when I scale up to handling multiple requests concurrently, the changes I've made have somehow resulted in all request being handled serially, by a single thread. Obviously, I'm doing something wrong.

I cannot post the entirety of the actual code I'm using, due to employer restrictions, but suffice it to say, I've kept the async calls to accept new connections, but have replaced the async read/writes with synchronous calls. If there are specific pieces that you think you need to see, I can see what I can do.

Essentially, what I'm looking for are pointers in how to use boost::asio for a multithreaded TCP server where individual connections are handled by a single thread with synchronous I/O. Again, keep in mind, my abstraction is based upon the http server example #2 (one io_service per CPU), but I am flexible to altern

Comment: Just out of interest why did you strip out the async_read/write calls? It's asynchronous IO that is going to allow you to scale... Presumably you've confirmed that the `io_service` has indeed been configured with the number of thread you need?

Comment: I always found ASIO to be lacking in documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The Boost.Asio [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html) suggests using a single `io_service` per application, and invoking `io_service::run` from a pool of threads.

It's also not obvious to me why you cannot use asynchronous `read` and `write` combined with `deadline_timer` objects to periodically ping your clients. Such a design will almost certainly scale better than a thread-per-connectiong using synchronous `reads` and `writes`.

Comment: Async is not necessarily more scalable than thread-per-connection now that linux has lightweight threads. Windows has long had lightweight threads. In fact I've seen benchmarks showing it's less scalable: http://www.mailinator.com/tymaPaulMultithreaded.pdf what's old is new again...

Answer (score 0):

Some diagnostics: can you print the value of `io_service_pool_.get_io_service()` before using it in the following code?

```
// from server.cpp
void server::handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{
  if (!e)
  {
    new_connection_->start();
    new_connection_.reset(new connection(
          io_service_pool_.get_io_service(), request_handler_));
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection_->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }
}
```

You'll need to store it in a temporary before passing it to `new_connection_.reset()`; that is, don't call `get_io_service()` twice for this test.

We first must make sure you're getting a new `io_service`.

Comment: I had done that. I'd instrumented the io_service_pool to spit out the address of each io_service instance returned, and I saw the addresses rotate, like I'd expect. The gotcha was that in the invocation of the request handler, the server always used the same thread (spat out boost::current_thread::get_id() to std::cerr). And the invocation of request_handler is where I spend the major of my time...

Comment: Also, for reference, I'm on a 4-core box for the server, using 8 threads and testing with 48 client threads spread across several machines.

Comment: What about the `io_service` in your reader? Since you're using synchronous calls, you don't have a "read handler" per se, but presumably you have some other logic in `connection::start()` before passing control to the request handler.

Comment: I'm still not sure why the synchronous calls always go to the same thread. I've switched back to using the async methods and with no other changes started seeing the separate `io_service`'s used. At this point, I don't know if there's any advantage to using an `io_service` pool, versus a single `io_service` w/ a thread pool. I'll probably switch back to the single `io_service` approach. My one concern is error handling in my second use case. I suppose I could test the socket to see if it's still connected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing lots of synchronous I/O, your concurrency is limited to the number of threads you have. I would suggest having one io_service for all your asynchronous I/O (ie: all the comms, timers) as you have now, and then decide on how to deal with the synchronous I/O.

For the synchronous I/O you need to decide what your peak concurrency will be. Because it is synchronous and it is I/O, you will want more threads that CPUs, and the decision will be based on how much I/O concurrency you want. Use a separate io_service, and then use io_service::dispatch() to distribute work into the threads doing the synchronous workload.

Doing it this way avoids the problem of a blocking I/O call stopping processing on other asynchronous events.